# How to send email to AWS SES from GCP vm instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ses, nat, squid

I have a requirement where GCP VM instance which is behind a squid proxy and NAT gateway should be able to send emails to AWS SES.

SES: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

as far as I know, GCP has port 25 blocked and after referring to few articles on stackoverflow, it seems squid does not support SMTP as well.

can someone please help if they have worked on similar thing before?.

Thanks
Max

Comment: You want to send email from outside to AWS SES, right? I only know the solution to send email from AWS SES.

Comment: That's right. email will originate from a GCP VM instance which is behind a squid proxy and proxy is behind a cloud NAT in GCP.

Comment: Have you checked [Squid E-Mail Configuration](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/HelpOnConfiguration/EmailSupport)? Do you want to use `email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` as an external SMTP relay for your GCP VM?

Comment: Hi, did you find good solution for this? I have same problem, in my case, Azure - AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Use port 587. As per [AWS SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html)  and [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail) documentation port 587 is without any restriction.

Comment: Thanks. does port 587 need to be whitelisted on squid or on the GCP VM from where email will originate. also, will squid allow SMTP traffic?.

Comment: If squid lives on the same VM, then no need. If on a different host then the application should able to connect to squid..

Comment: I have found another approach to allow the source subnet to directly NAT and I have whitelisted NAT external IP's in SES IAM policy. This works and emails are going through but here is my concern:

a) Now traffic is going to go directly to NAT, instead through proxy, as I have allowed source subnet directly in cloud NAT. 

b) is there a way, that I can keep this approach and just allow email traffic originating from source subnet to go to cloud NAT and then to outside?.

Answer (score 0):

##### Option 1, AWS SES HTTP API:

If the email sending application could support sending emails via AWS SES with the use of their HTTP API instead of the SMTP protocol, you could allow [that regional HTTPS endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html) in the outbound firewall (Squid in your case.)

The advantages of this approach address your concerns on bypassing the proxy by going through Cloud NAT directly, and maintaining restrictions on traffic originating from the source subnet.

##### Option 2, AWS SES SMTP over TLS:

Configure the application to connect with AWS SES SMTP endpoints on port 465 or 2465 while using TLS. This is also called SMTP**S** (where the trailing S stands for SSL/TLS, just like in HTTP**S**.) This is documented under [TLS Wrapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html) in AWS' documentation.

Since Squid is primarily a proxy for HTTP, you will be better of replacing it with an outbound firewall that supports filtering traffic by FQDNs for SSL/TLS connections wrapping any protocol within. (In this case, SMTP wrapped in TLS.) These are typically called [NGFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-generation_firewall) and available from the GCP marketplace on a free trial. One advantage of using these is the applications don't need explicit proxy settings for connecting to the Internet as the operation is completely transparent.